# Google Api Client: Not connected. Call Connect or wait for onConnected() to be called

Tags: android, google-play, background-process, google-fit

I'm actually trying to fetch Google fit steps from a background service. Let's call my service FitService.java.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    if(mFitnessClient == null){
        buildFitnessClient();
        Log.d(TAG, "FitnessClient created");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onHandleIntent");
    //block until google fit connects.  Give up after 10 seconds.
    if (!mFitnessClient.isConnected() && !mFitnessClient.isConnecting()) {
        mTryingToConnect = true;
        mGoogleApiFitnessClient.connect();

        //Wait until the service either connects or fails to connect
        while (mTryingToConnect) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100, 0);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    if (mFitnessClient.isConnected()) {
        getSteps();
        Log.i(TAG, "google api client connected. ");
    } else {
        //Not connected
        Log.e(TAG, "Fit wasn't able to connect, so the request failed.");
    }
}

private void buildFitnessClient() {
    // Create the Google API Client
    mGoogleApiFitnessClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ_WRITE))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ_WRITE))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(
                    new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {

                        @Override
                        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Google Fit connected.");
                            mTryingToConnect = false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                            // If your connection to the sensor gets lost at some point,
                            // you'll be able to determine the reason and react to it here.
                            mTryingToConnect = false;
                            if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Google Fit Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
                            } else if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Google Fit Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
                            }
                        }
                    }
            )
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(
                    new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                        // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                            mTryingToConnect = false;
                        }
                    }
            )
            .build();
}

public void getStepsToday(){
    long total = 0;

    PendingResult<DailyTotalResult> result = Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal(mGoogleApiFitnessClient, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);
    DailyTotalResult totalResult = result.await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if (totalResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        DataSet totalSet = totalResult.getTotal();
        total = totalSet.isEmpty()
                ? 0
                : totalSet.getDataPoints().get(0).getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt();
            Log.i(TAG, "Total steps are the same: " + total);
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "There was a problem while getting the step count.");
    }
}
```

It works fine for a majority of phone devices. But on some other devices I get a strange error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd.zzre(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd.zzrf(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzctu.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcd.zzpY(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcd.begin(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcx.zzd(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbbi.onConnected(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa.onConnected(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzn.zzj(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze.zzrj(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi.zzrk(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzh.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

GoogleApiHandler
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:148)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:151)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Any clue?